# Node with MongoDB Atlas docker image return empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect `express.js` with `MongoDB Atlas` and `mongoose`, but server always returns an empty array `[ ]`. When I load a local database everything works (`MongoDB` locally and `MongoDB Atlas` have the same values)

This problem comes while running a node app in a `docker` container. Data is available in the database but it always returns an empty array. But if I make same request without the `docker` container then I can get the data.

Can anyone help with this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample code or something  that can be use to understand and reproduce your problem.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If your connection function is successful, and your query is written properly,  then you're getting an empty array because there isn't any data in the collection you're querying.

Are you sure you're connecting to the right database and collection? Are you sure your client is connecting to the instance of MongoDB that think it is? You should look carefully for errors like these.

Comment: And i can able to find issue. issue is some data values i have updated manually in mongodb atlas. only that specific collection only returning the empty array. remaining all collection is working fine in docker. eventhough i have manually edited the values, in local system without docker everything works but within docker those specific docker is not working.